# How to refresh ads in Google Ad Manager (DFP) by using Line Item ID

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I have a question about how to refresh ads by providing the Line Item ID,

my case is, I have 2 versions of creative for each line items, so how can I refresh the ads, by providing the Line Item ID. I can get the Line Item ID by using this function:

```
    googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
      var slot = event.slot;
      console.group('Slot', slot.getSlotElementId(), 'finished rendering.');
      console.log('Line Item ID:', event.lineItemId);

    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the slot so if the lineItemId is the one you’re looking for you can just call
googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]);

Comment: Hi Thanks For quick response,
but how can I insert my lineItemId to this function:

googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]);

Does it make the ads load the ads creative based on the lineitem id?

Comment: You don’t pass the line item Id to refresh. The way you define your line item in Google Ad Manager determines which slots it matches. You might pass a targeting property called position in defineSlot with the value set to LB1 to indicate its the first leaderboard sized ad on the page, you can define a key/value for a  line item that will match slots with targeting property location=LB1.

Comment: I'm still stuck in this momment, could you please tell me the exact sample?

Comment: @Dmitryadam : if you have 2 creatives in one line item, weighted to 50% SOV each, when you refresh the adslot, le called line items will try to balance creative1 and creative2 automatically. So you just need to refresh the adslot.

Comment: Do you want to refresh only those ads associated with a certain lineItem?  In that case, you have to create your own data structure to hold this information.
var items  = []; 
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
      items[event.lineItemId] = (items[event.lineItemId] || []).concat(event.slot);
})
function refresh(lineId){
   (items[lineId]||[]).forEach(slot => googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]))}
   delete items[lineId];
}